# Bloomberg API (blpapi) Subscription not giving initial values

Tags: .net, bloomberg, blpapi

When I create and start a subscription using blpapi... it seems that I am only getting values sent to me as they change. I had expected that I would get an initial value for everything I requested... and then only get values when they change. But this doesn't seem to be the case.

I am asking for "LAST_PRICE,PX_CLOSE_1D,BID,ASK"... I am getting frequent updates for BID, ASK and LAST_PRICE... but I never see a value for PX_CLOSE_1D... and I'm guessing it's because it changes only once a day.

For that matter in the evening when it's pretty slow... sometimes it takes quite a while for LAST_PRICE to show up.

Is there a way to ask it to give me all values initially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PX_CLOSE_1D` is a static field, i.e. it does not update in real time. To get real time updates you can use a real time field, for example `PREV_CLOSE_VALUE_REALTIME`.

Comment: How can I retrieve the static value?

Comment: You would need to use a ReferenceDataRequest instead of the subscription process. There are a few examples in the developers guide.